# Calculating the max rounding diff when dividing x with x2

Tags: c#, .net, math, rounding

This might be 1/2 Math, 1/2 Programming question. But here we go.

I have a random decimal with 2 decimals. I am going to divide this with a random integer.
Then I would like to know the possible maximum rounding diff.

Example:

```
  decimal number = 100.00M;
  int x = 3;

  var result = number/x;
  var roundedResult = Round(result, 2, MidpointRoundingEx.AwayFromZero);
  // roundedResult = 33.33

  var roundingDiff = number - (roundedResult * x);
  // roundingDiff = 0.01
```

So I this example the rounding diff is 0.01.

But 'number' can be any number with 2 decimals and 'x' can be any integer. So I would like to know if its possible to put up a formula so I can know the largest rounding diff in any case.

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but why can't you just use the algorithm you posted?

Comment: I would like know know if its possible to mathematical proof the max  roundingDiff, given the two inputs.

Comment: If you want to proof mathematics then why don't ask your question here http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: "random decimal with 2 decimals" means there are two digits to the right of the decimal point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you want math - let's do fun!

Let's say that d is your random decimal number with two decimals.

We can easily say that

```
100d = n * x + r, 

where 100d, n, x, r are integers, and 0 <= r < x
```

so,

```
d / x = n / 100 + r / 100x
```

here n / 100 will always be "good" from rounding perspective, so we are interesting in "r / x" part, as it is the only part which affects rounding:

```
0 <= r / x < 1,
0 <= r / 100x < 0.01
```

If r / 100x >= 0.005, it adds 0.01 to rounded result. This is the same as r / x >= 1/2, which is the same as r >= x / 2

Ok, so (d / x) rounded is either

```
(1) n / 100, when r < x / 2, or
(2) n / 100 + 0.01, when r >= x / 2
```

Rounded difference is

```
diff = d - (n / 100) * x              for (1), or
diff = d - (n / 100) * x + 0.01 * x   for (2)
```

as of

```
(n / 100) * x  = d - r/100
```

we have that max diff will be for (2):

```
max diff = r / 100 + 0.01 * x = (r + x) / 100
```

but as we know

```
x / 2 <= r < x,
```

so max diff will be for maximum r: (*)

```
max diff = 2 * x * 0.01 = x / 200
```

As you see, we still depending on particular x, so we need to have some estimate on it. If it is completely random - we can have any rounding diff **up to d itself**.

If for example we say x < d then we have max diff = d / 200

And to add programming part:

```
        decimal number = 100.00M;

        decimal max = decimal.MinValue;
        decimal min = decimal.MaxValue;

        int maxX = 0;
        int minX = 0;

        for (int x = 1; x <= number; x++)
        {
            var result = number / x;
            var roundedResult = Math.Round(result, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            var roundingDiff = number - (roundedResult * x);
            if (roundingDiff < min)
            {
                min = roundingDiff;
                minX = x;
            }
            if (roundingDiff > max)
            {
                max = roundingDiff;
                maxX = x;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Max is {0} for {1}", max, maxX);
        Console.WriteLine("Min is {0} for {1}", min, minX);
        Console.WriteLine("Delta is {0}", max - min);
        Console.WriteLine("d / 200 = {0}", number / 200);
```

We have output:

```
Max is 0.40 for 83
Min is -0.44 for 93
Delta is 0.84
d / 200 = 0.50
```

Why not exactly 0.5? Because in (*) we had implicit assumption that r can be x/2 for any x, which is not true, but hopefully it is enough for you purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate diff using this one-liner formula:

```
var roundingDiff = ((int)(number * 100) % x - ((int)(number * 100) % x + x / 2) / x * x) / 100M;
```

For given `x`, the max rounding diff is `x / 200`